# Clicking A Link Two Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

I have a link like this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="renkDegistir()" title="Yaz .......
```

And JS code :

```
function renkDegistir()
    {  
        $("#cont #main article").addClass("siyah-stil");
    }
```

When click this link siyah-stil class is added to article. But i want to do, if link clicked 2nd time remove siyah-stil class.

In summary ,

```
on first click : addClass("siyah-stil");
on second click : removeClass("siyah-stil");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
function renkDegistir()
{
    $("#cont #main article").toggleClass("siyah-stil");
}
```

But I'd suggest also removing the in-line `onclick` attribute, and switching to jQuery's [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event-handler:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        $("#cont #main article").toggleClass("siyah-stil");
    });
```

---

**Edited** to address @Eray's comment (below):

> Can you explain [to] me , why jQuery's `click()` function [is] better than in-line `onclick` attribute?

The reason I prefer to use non-inline code is that it reduces the complexity of changing the `onClick` events; since they get changed in *one* place, rather than having to change the `onclick` attribute in every `a` (or other) element. Admittedly, you *could* achieve that benefit by simply changing the `renkDegistir()` function, but then you end up with functions named for posterity, rather than the inherent nature of the function.

It also makes it easier for others to take over, and adapt your code, and to iron out bugs when they appear.

Comment: @Eray: then you should probably add the other information into your question, so that we can help you properly...

Comment: Thank you david . Can you explain me , why jQuery's click() function better than in-line onclick attr ?

Comment: @Eray: I've given a couple of reasons that **I** prefer to use jQuery's `click` handler.

Comment: (reply of your edit) you right . But i'm using renkDegistir function only one page's , one <a> tag :) So , i can use in-line attributes :) But , if i have to use a lot of in-line attrs , your method is better. (Sorry for my fantastic English :) )

Answer (score 1):

`toggleClass` does exactly that.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

[JQuery - toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)